# Remove blank lines appearing between non-blank lines without a regex?

Tags: whitespace, join

What is the quickest way to un-doublespace in Vim, without using a regex?

I.e., convert

```
line one
<emptyline>
line two
<emptyline>
line three
```

to

```
line one
line two
line three
```

There's gotta be a way without regexes, by using `J` somehow.

Comment: With literally three lines `JjJ` works (assuming the cursor starts on the first line), but that's going to get old fast. Why not `%s/\n\n/\r/`?

Comment: @Telemachus Yeah, maybe regex isn't that much longer. Using `J` would seem to require  a macro to do the repetitions for arbitrary number of lines.

Comment: @Quasímodo Yes, by double-spaced I mean lines interleaved with blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on linux, you could call an external program to filter a range of
lines (here I filter all of them with `%`):

```
:%! awk NF
```

In the above awk command, NF indicates the total number of fields, and hence
this prints only non-blank lines, since in blank lines NF is 0 and evaluates to
false.

Not sure if it's faster, but it's a different way (note this will just remove all blank lines from the document).

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive mapping. Define it with

```
:nmap <F2> gg}gJ<F2>
```

and then press <kbd>F2</kbd>. The mapping will go to the start of the file (`gg`), search for the next empty line (`}`), and try to to join the empty line with the next line, respecting leading indent (`gJ`). If `gJ` can join an empty line with the next line, the mapping will continue and call itself recursively (`<F2>`); otherwise it will abort.

Note that this mapping will keep all empty lines at the start of the file and will reduce two or more empty lines at the end of the file to one empty line.

Answer (score 1):

This technically involves a regular expression, but if it's only a single blank line:

```
:global/./join
" aka
:g/./j
```

Comment: That's a shorter regex. 

Answer (score 0):

Not faster than using `s/\n\n/\r/`, but this is a macro way of doing it:

```
qxJjq
```

Select the region you're interested in, then:

```
:'<,'>norm @x
```

to repeatedly execute macro `x` on it.

Comment: Defining and then calling a macro for this is not just "not faster." It's significantly more work, and for no good reason that I can see.

Comment: @Telemachus Sure, but I'd like to know how the do it without a regex.